# Font Awesome icons not working in existing PowerPoint presentations

Tags: font-awesome-5

I am experiencing exactly the same problem on PowerPoint 2010 as posted by a FontAwesome user on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1169693/fontawesome-not-working-on-specific-powerpoint-presentation) months ago that did not receive any response.

To quote from that user:

"I've installed FontAwesome on my computer (Windows 10 Pro, 64bits) and I've been trying to use it on a PowerPoint 2013 presentation without success.

The problem is that if I create a new presentation, the font works without problems (even I can copy and paste the icons of the cheatsheet and it works). However, on this already created presentation, if I copy and paste the icons, they appear as blank spaces or squares.

I've tried unchecking "Embed fonts" when saving the document, I've tried to uninstall and install again the font, restarting the computer, clearing the Windows font cache... none of them works.

If I create a new PowerPoint and copy&paste the slides, I've got the same problem in the new PowerPoint: the font does not work."

This is a really fundamental problem because unless it is fixed it's impractical to use Font Awesome as our company's standard icon package.

Comment: I just had this problem when I installed FontAwesome 5+. When I reinstalled 4, and added the font the icons showed up in my existing presentation.

Comment: The link for the superuser question  is not working